# What add to python-behave to create logging file?

Tags: python, logging, python-behave

Logging not work in my program, when I use behave. This code work and create a log file_results_q.log only when I run this program as python program.

When I use behave, i can see a "test test" in windows PowerShell, but log file_results_q.log is not creating.

I use "--no-logcapture" in Windows PowerShell to run behave

**code:**

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename=r"D:\test\testy\logfile_results_q.log")
logging.info("test")
@given('project folder path: / {solver_name}')
def step_impl(context, solver_name):
    logging.info("test test")
```

What I should add to this code, to behave work with logging properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`logging.basicConfig` is configuring the root logger. Better, create your own logger:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('logfile_results_q')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create file handler which logs even debug messages
fh = logging.FileHandler(r"D:\test\testy\logfile_results_q.log")
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.info("test")
```

Note the `logger.info()`, not the `logging.info()`

See the [Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html) page for more examples.

Comment: Very thanks for the answer. I see that you use FileHandler method to configure filename. Do you know how to set a different parameter? in original  program i have to set: logging.basicConfig(filename="...", format="...", datefmt="...", filemode="...", level="...")

Comment: The FileHandler constructor has other parameters as well: `logging.FileHandler(filename, mode='a', encoding=None, delay=False)`.

The Logging Cookbook link shows how to add a log formatter.

Answer (score 2):

The python-behave logging overwrites your basicConfig. The same is possible when you import packages. It is better you specify your own logger.  See for this the answer from @ababak or the official documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html

(search for 'Configuring Logging')

Answer (score 0):

The logging module has a not-well known "feature".
`logging.basicConfig(...)` can only be called once (if you do not hack the module). Second calls to `logging.basicConfig(...)` are ignored because the logging module is already set-up.

Therefore, **behave** needs to setup the logging module, otherwise other configuration aspects would not work. If you try to do it yourself, the logging module (and behave) "bites you".

SEE ALSO:

- [Example: Setup logging with behave by using a config-file](https://github.com/behave/behave/blob/master/features/logging.setup_with_configfile.feature)
- behave: `features/logging.*.feature`, `features/logcapture.*.feature`